How to select a cell and get values in Fortune Sheet React | SpreadSheet
Hello Guys I want to add a function which is library built in function getCellValue and i want to utilize it to get the selected cell value or range of values but i cant find any code in library to integrate that , below is my code
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import { Workbook } from "@fortune-sheet/react";
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from "react-redux"
import "@fortune-sheet/react/dist/index.css"
import  {data} from "./data"
import { GetUserSheetData } from '../../../../../../Redux/SheetSlice';

const Sheet = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const [workbookData, setWorkbookData] = useState(null);


    let celldata = [];
    //Converting the Columns to Numeric Values
    const getColumnNumber = (column) => {
      const alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
      let colNumber = 0;
    
      // If the column reference is a single character, return its index
      if (column.length === 1) {
        return alphabet.indexOf(column.toUpperCase());
      }
    
      // For multi-character column references like "AA", "AB", etc.
      for (let i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
        const char = column.charAt(i); // Get the current character
        const charIndex = alphabet.indexOf(char.toUpperCase()) + 1; // Get the index of the character in the alphabet
        colNumber = colNumber * 26 + charIndex; // Calculate the numeric value of the column
      }
    
      return colNumber - 1; // Adjusting to start from 0
    };

    // Loop through the data array to construct the celldata
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        const col = getColumnNumber(data[i].column)

        celldata.push({
            r: data[i].rows,
            c: col,
            v:{
              v:data[i].value,
              m:data[i].value,
              bg:""
            }
        });
    }

    const handleChange = (data) => {
      console.log(data)
    }


    const handleSelectChange = (workbook) => {
      const selectedRange = workbook.getSelectedRange();
      const selectedCellValue = workbook.getCellValues(selectedRange.row, selectedRange.col);
      console.log(selectedCellValue);
    };


    const settings = {
        data: [{
          name: 'Sheet1',
          celldata: celldata
      }],
        onChange: handleChange,
        onSelectChange: handleSelectChange,
        lang: 'en',
        row:50
    };


  return (
    <div className=' w-full h-full flex flex-col gap-2  ' >
         <Workbook {...settings} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Sheet

Is My handleSelectChange a right way to do so to apply different builtin library funtions

If I understand correctly, your requirement is to be able to get the current cells selected in the sheet. While fortunesheet does not provide an inbuilt event emitter for this, you can use the getSelection method defined in its API to get this range where you want.
Docs | Storybook Demo
For example -
const workbookRef = useRef(null);

// call the below line on some event or where you need it
workbookRef.current.getSelection();
// example return value -  [{"row":[0,1],"column":[1,4]}]

return  <Workbook data={[cellData]} onChange={handleSheet} ref={workbookRef} lang="en" />


Thank u it works like i try it in onChange event when ever i am changing cell data it is returning an array of row and column but , i don't wan to do it  on change either i want it to do when ever user select the cell or rolumn , and directly add ur code does not works properly so i think there will be an event like from chatgpt i try onSelectionChange which gpt provide but that doesn't works

Is there any selection event to trigger a specific operation while selecting a column or row , i didn't see any in library

onSelectionChange does not exist in the library, and as I said there is no inbuilt event emitter in fortunesheet for cell selection. For that you might want to have your own click listener.

Kindly consider marking this as the accepted answer if it resolves your query.

Can i ask if u have done that before can u plz share code

I've not done that, but you can just have a simple on click listener in your code which can save the selection details in a state.
